# How to hide a div by clicking outside it?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I know there are many such solutions on jQuery. But so far I can not adapt these solutions for myself with the help of Angular. I have an isOpenSharedLinkDiv variable that uses * ngIf to show or hide a div. I try to translate this value to false when I click outside of this div, but in this case the div does not open at all. I think I'm missing something.

```
test() {
    console.log(this.isOpenSharedLinkDiv);
    // const div = document.querySelector('#sharing-basket-div');
    const div = document.querySelector('.page');
    // const icon = document.querySelector('#sharing-basket-icon');
    const shareDiv = document.querySelector('#share');

    div.addEventListener('click', ev => {
      if (ev.target !== shareDiv || ev.target === div && this.isOpenSharedLinkDiv === true) {
        // this.isOpenSharedLinkDiv = false;
        console.log(ev.target);
        console.log(this.isOpenSharedLinkDiv);
      } else {
        return;
      }
    });
  }
```

As a result, this variable turns out to be false, even when it is not open yet.

Comment: what exactly your expected outcome? you used *ngIf to hide div but when to show? on which action?

Comment: Could you show more code ? Hard to tell from here what's going on.

Comment: not sure if it really requires a directive , if you could post your html code here  that would help to find a better solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a really simple directive to do this:

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, HostListener, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[clickOutside]'
})
export class UnoClickOutsideDirective {
  constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef) {}

  @Output() clickOutside: EventEmitter<null> = new EventEmitter<null>();

  @HostListener('document:click', ['$event.target']) onMouseEnter(targetElement) {
    const clickedInside = this.elementRef.nativeElement.contains(targetElement);
    if (!clickedInside) {
      this.clickOutside.emit(null);
    }
  }
}
```

This directive applied to any element, tells you when you click outside of it. So you can use it with a div like this:

**component.html**

```
<div *ngIf="condition" (clickOutside)="condition=false"></div>
```

**component.ts**

```
condition: boolean = true;
```

Comment: Improvement would be to use 2-way binding for the `condition` so that you don't have to use an output, but +1 anyway

Comment: @trichetriche I like how you're thinking :), I'll change the answer to implement both... But in this particular case, I can't see a real improvement in using 2 way binding... Ok, I don't have to set the `condition` property inside the component template, but I have to add an Input in the directive. Is it a best practice anyway? Could you please enlighten me about it?

Comment: Honestly I don't know if it's good or bad practice. I personnally would say good, because it reduces the amount of code you have to write when USING the directive (not *making* it). And it's simply a [structural directive](https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives), with the `*myDirective` syntax : since it's written like a `*ngIf`, it makes things way easier in my opinion !

Comment: You're right. "*because it reduces the amount of code you have to write when USING the directive (not making it)*" this is actually enough to accept your solution as a really nice improvement. Thank you very much for the clarification :).